# Re-usable content within a web part

Tags: 2013, web-part

I would like to create some content, like a customized text box with a "motto of the month", that is used on some pages, but not everywhere.

Is there a way that does not require deploying a web part that can do that?

(Sharepoint 2013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have two options for this.

1. Using a customized page layout - This will contain the moto at some place. When you need, you can change the page layout and publish it.
2. Create a custom webpart that will show the moto, which is a text taken from a property bag value. In that case, you do not need to do anything with the webpart. You just have to change the property bag value.

Here is how to use the JavaScript CSOM to [query a property bag value](http://www.jeremythake.com/2013/10/using-the-sharepoint-csom-api-to-get-a-property-bag-value/).

Comment: I like to use these webparts also as part of general views for document libraries, so I don't think I can generally work with the layout (not so many options?)

Comment: How would #2 work? Do I need to deploy the web part?

Comment: Yes you will have to deploy a Visual WebPart. Then add it to each page you need.

Comment: Thanks for your help -- unfortunately deploying web parts is not possible in this case due to company policy.

Comment: Can you list me what you are allowed to do?

Comment: I can do anything that I can do on a Site level, but not on a Site Collection/Farm level.

Comment: I have edited the question to show how to use JS CSOM to read a propertybag value. Use it and deploy a JavaScript code in a content editor and display the property bag value 'moto of the month'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16900/discussion-between-danieldekay-and-malin-de-silva).